# Apt update - stuck on 0%

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, apt

I have problem with "0% Working". I saw [same posts](https://askubuntu.com/questions/498462/apt-get-stuck-at-0-working?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) before, tried to do what there adviced but it dont help me.
My system is:

```
  lsb_release -a No LSB modules are available. Distributor ID: Ubuntu
 Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS Release:        16.04 Codename:    
 xenial
```

I have

[image: My problem is 0% Working]

I have Google DNS

```
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver 8.8.4.4
nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

I have good ping to ubuntu site:

```
PING us.archive.ubuntu.com (91.189.91.26) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from hanger.canonical.com (91.189.91.26): icmp_seq=1 ttl=54 time=127 ms
...
```

Here my  /etc/apt/sources.list https://pastebin.com/usJHp95b

Now i see that i cant install any programm like "dig" or nmap:

```
sudo apt install nmap
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package nmap
```

Previos time all worked fine. What i did before: 1) Installed OpenVPN for tests. 2) Get new router from my ISP but seems like i did there same settings for network. 3) Our dear goverment block Telegram (over 15 million IP adress Google and Amazon, maybe here a problem?)

Also i have message from system when i logged in system from monitor (not ssh),
"sendbytes: NAK bailout. "
its repeat every 5 sec +-

Sorry for bad english! 
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two suggestions:

- Try changing the update server location from US to where your proxy
  is hosted(Russia maybe?) in "Software and Updates":

[image]

- Try changing the
  sources.list to suit your demographics [here](https://repogen.simplylinux.ch/).

Comment: i changed today RU to US in sources.list (i tryied resolve this problem but no effect on russian and with US servers. I dont GUI but i think there all repo is enabled "main restricted universe multiverse"

Comment: Thanks alot - this link and you helped me!  Now all fine again!

Answer (score 0):

Method 1: Badly Configured resolv.conf File
resolv.conf is a file for configuring DNS servers on Linux systems.

To start, open the file in a text editor such as nano. You can use Vim also

sudo nano /etc/resolv.conf

Make sure the resolv.conf file contains at least one nameserver. The lines listing nameservers should look like this:

nameserver 8.8.8.8

then :

sudo systemctl restart systemd-resolved.service

Now try to ping the site again
ping us.archive.ubuntu.com